# Protect my motion webcam stream with a password (motion.conf)

Tags: streaming-video, webcam, motion, password

I set up a webcam server using [`motion`](http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion). The video is correctly streamed to Internet. Now I would like to protect the stream with a password: I don't want unknown people to spy on me! I don't know how to do this. In `motion.conf`, there are attributes:

- `control_authentification`

> To protect HTTP Control by username and password, use this option for HTTP 1.1 Basic authentication. The string is specified as username:password. Do not specify this option for no authentication. This option must be placed in motion.conf and not in a thread config file.

- `netcam_userpass`

> For network cameras protected by username and password, use this option for HTTP 1.1 Basic authentication. The string is specified as username:password. Do not specify this option for no authentication.

I don't understand these two arguments so I tried both of them but it did not work...

Answer (score 6):

To setup a username and password with motion, you need to edit motion configuration file.
Steps

1. Open terminal
2. Type `sudo nano /etc/motion/motion/conf`
3. Add in a new line `stream_auth_method 1`
4. Add in a new line `stream_authentication username:password`
5. Ctrl + X
6. Press Y, Press Enter

Answer (score 3):

`netcam_userpass` is to connect motion to a webcam that is protected by a username and password. This can happen for instance, if you are running a webcam program on a cellphone and have set a username/pass there.

In order to protect your motion cam to the outside internet, you'd need to setup either an Apache or Nginx proxy to a cgi program (mjprox) that watches motion, with http authentication attached (htaccess / htpasswd).

[Information on mjprox can be found here.](http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/MjpegProxyGrab)